# NSTimer stops in the background after some time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I used NSTimer to call a method after 1 sec when app goes in background and after nearly 17 minutes timer stops working.

When it came back in the foregound it again started working, so please tell me why this is happening and how to resolve the issue.

I also tried using perform selector with delay in recursion for the same purpose, but again giving the same result. Please suggest any solution. Any help will be completely appreciated.

Comment: What does the timer do? I mean, is one of the apple's permited background tasks?

Comment: What "Required background modes" have you set in your build target properties?

Comment: I have added "app register for location updates" in my Required background modes

Comment: Please suggest me how to achieve this task.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wierd issue- i too had this one, but the following worked for me.

```
 //Run the timer on the runloop to ensure that it works when app is in background

  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:self.timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: I have used this but still the timer stops after nearly 16 minutes in the background

Comment: Please see this and let me know if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449351/iphone-4-is-there-an-absolutely-certain-way-to-have-a-long-term-nstimer-fire?rq=1

Comment: Runloop is not working in device. Do have idea why it's not working ?

Answer (score 5):

From [Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24):

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Answer (score 0):

If few minutes isn't enough, you **can't make an app run infinite time in backgorund** *unless* it uses:

- Audio Playback
- Location Services
- External Accessory

You can use **Background Tasks** to get 10 minutes of running time for all other apps, or **Local Notifications** to notify user.

Comment: I m using location services for background mode but still timer stops